# How to exact a number using xpath through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Hi I am trying to locate an element containing text '01.0000', but there is a source code containing '01.00' before this line. How can I locate this element?

source code:

```
<div class="gofer-search-results">
<a href="#" class="js-hovered"><span class="name">Communication and Media Studies</span><span class="code">09.01</span></a>
<a href="#" class=""><span class="name">Communication, General</span><span class="code">09.0100</span></a>
<a href="#" class=""><span class="name">Speech Communication and Rhetoric</span><span class="code">09.0101</span></a>
<a href="#" class=""><span class="name">Mass Communication/Media Studies</span><span class="code">09.0102</span></a>
<a href="#" class=""><span class="name">Communication and Media Studies, Other</span><span class="code">09.0199</span></a>
<a href="#" class=""><span class="name">Animal Sciences</span><span class="code">01.09</span></a></div>
```

here are the codes I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/div/a/span[text()= 01.0000]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/div/a/span[normalize-space()= 01.0000]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/div/a/span[./text()= 01.0000]")
```

I kept getting 01.00 element instead of 01.0000 element.

Comment: Please add the source code in text and also please add what errors you have come up with.

Comment: Just did. Thanks

Comment: This works for me `[x for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/a/span") if x.text=='09.0100']`

Comment: I forgot to put in the ' '. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate this element with text as **01.0000** you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *text()*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/div/a/span[text()='01.0000']")
  ```
- Using *normalize-space()*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/div/a/span[normalize-space()='01.0000']")
  ```